# Cannot sum more than 9 input javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a small issue in my script and I cannot get the sum for more than 9 inputs.

Up to 9 is working good, but if you add a new input field this stops working.

Div whit input and buttons:

```
<div id="valuesContainer">
<input type="text" id="value01" />
<input type="text" id="value02" />
<input type="text" id="value03" />
<input type="text" id="value04" />
<input type="text" id="value05" />
<input type="text" id="value06" />
<input type="text" id="value07" />
<input type="text" id="value08" />
<input type="text" id="value09" />

</div>
<input type="button" value="Add Value" id="addMore" onclick="addInput();" />
<input type="button" value="Calculate Total" onclick="getTotal();" />
<div id="total"></div>
```

Javascript doing the sum with a function to add new input fields.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
var max = 9;

function getValues(id){
    var result = document.getElementById(id).value;
    return (result ? result : 0);
}

function addInput(){
    max++;
    var input = '<input type="text" id="value'+ max +'" />';
    document.getElementById("valuesContainer").innerHTML += input;
}

function getTotal(){
    var sum = 0;
    for(var i=1; i <= max; i++){
        sum = sum + parseFloat(getValues("value0" + i));
    }
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = sum;
}
    </script>
```

Comment: This is not really worth being its own question, you should clarify your [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14420570/how-to-get-auto-javascript-input-fields) instead. Also, you cannot ask questions on Stackoverflow as alternative to learning the actual material. It won't get you far.

Comment: But to help you: Why do you use IDs at all? `getElementsByTagName` is probably much more flexible in the long run: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName.

Answer (score 8):

Notice in your code you are explicitly adding "value0" before the index in:

```
sum = sum + parseFloat(getValues("value0" + i));
```

With that code, your tenth index should be "value010"

---

You could instead prepend a "0" only if the index is less than 10:

```
if (i < 10)
   sum = sum + parseFloat(getValues("value0" + i)); 
else
   sum = sum + parseFloat(getValues("value" + i));
```

And then you can use "value10" for the tenth index, which is probably what you wanted originally.

You could do similar work for larger number or other cases. For a more general solution you may use a function to [pad the string to a given size](http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2011/08/23/javascript-leftright-pad-a-string/)

Answer (score 3):

How are you naming them?

My guess is you are using `value10`, but your code for getValues appends i to `value0`.  I would bet if you used `value010`, it would work.

If the next value has to be value10, you have two choices:

1.) Rename `value01` through `value09` to `value1` through `value9`

2.) Append the 0 only when i < 10:

```
for(var i=1; i <= max; i++){
     parseFloat(getValues("value" + ((i<10)? "0" + i : i)));
}
```

Comment: Well, in fact the next need to be value10 not value010, maybe i can start from 01 or 1 to get more than 10, the only problem is that i need to have preloaded 9 input fields. Thanks

Comment: Hello John, i cannot understand your solution. Thanks allot

Comment: @NeoCastelli What don't you understand?  The new getValues call uses a [ternary/conditional](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) operator, which is basically just an inline if statement.

Comment: your answer is converting to this, function getTotal(){
  var sum = 0;
  for(var i=1; i <= max; i++){
     parseFloat(getValues("value" + (i<10)? "0" + i : i));
 } and this is not working, that's im not understanding.

Comment: @NeoCastelli I missed a parentheses, try it with the updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your code says

```
getValues("value0" + i)
```

so for values of i > 9, it will look for ID "value010" etc. So if your additional inputs have IDs like

```
<input type="text" id="value10" />
```

then "value010" won't match "value10" and you won't find what you're looking for.